# Calculate mean for truncated Gamma distribution

Tags: r, mean, gamma-distribution

I am using the "gamlss" and "gamlss.tr" packages in R to simulate truncated Generalized Gamma distributions
The GG has three parameters mu, sigma and nu : see explanation  https://rdrr.io/cran/gamlss.dist/man/GG.html

Truncation can be done via:

```
library(gamlss)
library(gamlss.tr)
gen.trun(0.1,GG)
```

now I can simulate random numbers from that by:

`rGGtr(n,mu,sigma,nu)`

mu represents the mean, sigma the scale, nu the shape -see link above,

but why my mean is not the same if I only modify sigma? is this an numerial issue because with increasing sigma I have a higher chance for outliers?
e.g.

```
mean(rGGtr(10000,mu=1,sigma=1,nu=0.2))
mean(rGGtr(10000,mu=1,sigma=2,nu=0.2))
mean(rGGtr(10000,mu=1,sigma=3,nu=0.2))
mean(rGGtr(10000,mu=1,sigma=4,nu=0.2))
```

this gives me an increasing empirical mean although the mean should be 1 always?

Comment: The sample mean changes because `mu` is a parameter of the _untruncated_ distribution and you are sampling from the corresponding _truncated_ distribution, whose mean is a function of `sigma` also.

Comment: If I use the untruncated distribution, say rGG() instead of rGGtr(), with the same parameters as above, I get an increase in the empirical mean too, so I think there must be another reason?!

Comment: That is more concerning. I can replicate it, too: `mean(rGG(1e6, mu = 1, sigma = 1, nu = 0.2))` returns `1.458958`. It could be a bug in the documentation or in the code. `rGG` is just returning `qGG(runif(n), mu, sigma, nu)`, so you might want to check that `qGG` is returning accurate results for a range of `p` in (0,1). FWIW, many other packages have implemented the generalized gamma distribution. It could be worth comparing against one of those, though it seems most of them use the canonical parametrization (not this one).

Comment: I agree! -Have reached out to the R package maintainer

Comment: got feedback from the package maintainers. Here indeed the mu is not representing the mean, so typo in the docs.